# Set CSS Atribute Selector to :target

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Not sure if this is possible or not.

Trying to dynamically set an attribute selector to the current target (without the use of any JavaScript).

Something like this css:

```
.tab[href=#:target] {
  // styles here for active anchor tag
}
```

Where the html (in Jade syntax) is:

```
.tab-group
  a.tab(href="#tabA") Tab A
  a.tab(href="#tabB") Tab B
  a.tab(href="#tabC") Tab C

#tabA.target
.tab-content
  h2 Tab A
#tabB.target
.tab-content
  h2 Tab B
#tabC.target
.tab-content
  h2 Tab C
```

In other words: How to select the anchor link that set the current hashtag (with pure CSS, no JS).

Why? For CSS-only tabs using the `:target` pseudo selector approach that allow for the most flexible html structure possible.

Comment: This is not going to work without a very tiny bit of javascript, as the target is completely separate from any other elements and is not directly a string you can check for. So I would suggest `document.body.setAttribute('data-url-target',location.hash)` as the single line of JS, and then use `[data-url-target="#..."] ...` to create style selection rules for every possible ID.

Comment: This would require an idref combinator, which was proposed, but dropped. Attribute selectors cannot be parameterized in the way you describe. Any CSS-only approach would require assumptions to be made about your HTML and allow very little in the way of flexibility.

Comment: @BoltClock: Very helpful to know. It's too bad... It'd be really nice to be able to do this without any JS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different element types here related to the fragment identifier in the URL: there is the anchor element that the URL points to (the one with the same id as the hash in the URL) and there are the links that would point to the same URL as the current one.

[:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selects the anchor element. In order to select the links, you would have to use Javascript to get the URL and then use some sort of selector like [$=#YOURHASH (ends with)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp)

If you know the tabs in advance, you may create CSS rules like this:

```
.tabSomething .content a[href$=#Something] {
  // style for the links that lead to tab Something, because you know the hash is #Something for that tab
}
```

Comment: Looking for a CSS-only approach... I know this is easily achieved with JS.

Comment: @Isaac Gregson: Then there isn't one.

Comment: `.tabSomething .content a[href$=#Something]` will always match. The OP is looking for a selector that will match *iff* :target is matching its, well, target.

Comment: @Siderrite Zackwehdex: That was my hunch... too bad :(